# Activity Monitor Log: Default Browser

Tags: visual-studio, activitylog, default-browser

On clicking a notification below the menu bar in VS2019 16.8.2, the Activity Monitor Log opens in Internet Explorer.

The *Web Browser* section in *Options=>Environment* only has an Internet Options link for IE. Internet Explorer will be retired soon, is there, or will there be provision for sending the log to an alternative browser, or even another program, e.g. [this viewer](https://github.com/tahaipek/VisualStudioActivityMonitorLogViewer)?

Answer (score 1):

One thing not attempted before posting the question was to try the suggestion at [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019):

> By default, the log file is located here:
>
> %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio<Version>\ActivityLog.xml
>
> where  is the Visual Studio version. However, you may specify
> a different path and file name.

And also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2019):

> For example, the command devenv /log output.txt opens the IDE and
> outputs all log information for that session to output.txt.

Clicking on the IDE to launch the log is as per file association. The xml extension was for some reason defaulted to IE on this rig.

So, not really a problem, VS launches the file correctly by default, and as per file extension settings.

Comment: In recollection, the xml/IE association was because the clarity of the xml markup in IE was, and perhaps still is, second to none!